# How do I use ADODB resultsets in VBScript?

Tags: sql, vbscript, resultset, adodb

I am developing VBScript using ADODB and I have troubles finding clear information about how you are supposed to access resultsets for information once you've executed something like this:

```vb
Dim cmd
Dim resultSet

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection =  '--connection object you've configured
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM USER"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

set resultSet = cmd.Execute
```

Does my *resultSet* have a field for each ROW or a field each value (ROW_NUMBER * COLUMNS_PER_ROW) in the *USER* table?

Comment: These general questions can be answered via Google / SO search or MSDN docs.

Comment: VBA or VBScript, which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ADODB.Recordset` object

```
set objRecordset=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
```

Like this, or variants of this where I use `Open` aswell as an example (so please note I am duplicating some functions here in this code below):

```
Dim cn as new ADODB.Connection
Dim rs as new ADODB.Recordset
...
rs = cmd.Execute
...
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Table", cn    

While Not rs.EOF
  somevalue = rs("Field")
  ...
  rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
```

To answer your question, `Recordset` gives you a set of records, one record (row) at a time